# Accessing series data in tooltip formatter highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to calculate the difference between the total of 2 stacked columns for which I am trying to access series data in tooltip formatter. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: you can set the 'shared' property to true and access data from the other series using [these](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) methods.

Comment: If you do a **console.log(this)** inside the formatter function, you will see the various paths you can take.  With a standard tooltip, you can access the full chart object, and thereby the full series object, by going to **this.series.chart.series**  Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/yf17v055/1/  (load the chart, and check the console after hovering over a point)